# Extracting date and hour from Posixct object with strftime

Tags: r, date, datetime, sapply, strftime

I was trying to extract date and hour from a date time column using strftime but I don't understand why the values returned are 1 hour previous than the values that should be returned. For example for a date time of 2013-01-01 00:00:00 the values returned should be 2013-01-01 00 but instead what I'm getting is 2012-12-31 23. I also tried adding 1 hour and then extracting but over a long sequence of dates, it is again disturbing the output. Please see this sample code for reference.

```
## creating the sequence of time steps for cleaned
start <- as.POSIXct('2013-01-01 00:00:00',tz='EST')
end <- as.POSIXct('2016-06-06 23:00:00',tz='EST')

timesteps = data.frame( seq.POSIXt(from = start, to =end , by = "5 min"))
colnames(timesteps) = "Time Index"

dateandhour = function (timeindex){
return(strftime(timeindex, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H"))
}

timesteps ['Date and Hour'] = sapply(timesteps$`Time Index`, dateandhour)
```

Please let me know what is it that I'm missing here. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are specifying the time zone in `as.POSIXct`, but not in `strptime`.

```
timesteps[1,1]
[1] "2013-01-01 EST"

 strftime(timesteps[1,1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")
[1] "2012-12-31 21"
 strftime(timesteps[1,1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H",tz='EST')
[1] "2013-01-01 00"`

dateandhour = function (timeindex){
  return(strftime(timeindex, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H",tz='EST'))
}

timesteps ['Date and Hour'] = sapply(timesteps$`Time Index`, dateandhour)

head(timesteps)
           Time Index Date and Hour
1 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-01 00
2 2013-01-01 00:05:00 2013-01-01 00
3 2013-01-01 00:10:00 2013-01-01 00
4 2013-01-01 00:15:00 2013-01-01 00
5 2013-01-01 00:20:00 2013-01-01 00
6 2013-01-01 00:25:00 2013-01-01 00
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake with as.POSIXct. Your answer was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two-line answer:

#### Create the sequence

```
df <- data.frame(TimeIndex = 
         seq(anytime("2013-01-01 00:00:00"), 
             anytime("2016-06-06 23:00:00"), by="5 min"))
```

This create 361k observations:

```
R> dim(df)
[1] 360841      1
R>
```

#### Convert to Date and Hour

You can do this in one operation as R is vectorized:

```
df$DateAndHour <- strftime(df$TimeIndex, "%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

And we can check:

```
R> head(df, 10)
             TimeIndex   DateAndHour
1  2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-01 00
2  2013-01-01 00:05:00 2013-01-01 00
3  2013-01-01 00:10:00 2013-01-01 00
4  2013-01-01 00:15:00 2013-01-01 00
5  2013-01-01 00:20:00 2013-01-01 00
6  2013-01-01 00:25:00 2013-01-01 00
7  2013-01-01 00:30:00 2013-01-01 00
8  2013-01-01 00:35:00 2013-01-01 00
9  2013-01-01 00:40:00 2013-01-01 00
10 2013-01-01 00:45:00 2013-01-01 00
R>
```

I use [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) above as I find it compact and convenient -- not requiring a format.  We could have use `as.POSIXct()` or `strptime()` too.

I also omitted the `tz` argument so that everything is in my local timezone.  You can either set it on each call to `anytime()` and `strftime()`, or set the `TZ` environment variable.

*Edit:* As OP asked about performance, here is a quick comparison. I needed to alter the solultions slightly:

```
df <- data.frame(TimeIndex = seq(anytime("2013-01-01 00:00:00"),
                                 anytime("2016-06-06 23:00:00"), by="5 min"))

dateandhour <- function (timeindex) {
    return(strftime(timeindex, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H"))
}

f1 <- function(df) { data.frame(TimeIndex=df, DateAndHour=sapply(df, dateandhour)) }
f2 <- function(df) { data.frame(TimeIndex=df, DateAndHour=strftime(df$TimeIndex, "%Y-%m-%d %H")) }

library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(f1(df), f2(df), replications=10)[,1:4]
```

With that I get this:

```
R> benchmark(f1(df), f2(df), replications=10)[,1:4]
    test replications elapsed relative
1 f1(df)           10   7.101     2.08
2 f2(df)           10   3.414     1.00
R>
```

About a two-fold improvement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really liked your use of anytime to reduce the coding steps but which approach is more efficient for very large datasets?

Comment: A vectorized solution typically wins over sapply. See my expanded answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: So I wrote in effect two answers, and you couldn't be bothered to upvote it.  I also think what I have is clearly better than the accepted answers (contains all the logic offered in shorter -- and faster code). In short, that's not how it works around here because you provide _zero_ incentive.

Comment: Hi! I tried upvoting you after your first answer itself but it gives me a message saying "Thanks for your feedback. Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed score. "

Comment: My current reputation is 13 since I recently joined Stack overflow. Once I reach reputation 15, I'll make sure to upvote your answer. Thanks again for your answers.